# Is there a python library for generating fake data using data properties

Tags: python, code-generation

I use [*hypothesis*](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) for testing.

Now I find myself in need of exactly the same capability, but for generating fake data instead of for testing across many parameters.

## Question

- Is there any library that can do this?
- Is there any way to use the *hypothesis* library to generate fake data?

## Example

I have an object like this (the real object is far more complex):

```py
my_dict = {
  'name': 'Mike',
  'job': [
      {
        'title': 'manager',
        'location': 'remote'
      }
    ],
  'age': 50
}
```

and I want to be able to figure out that I have:

```py
my_dict = {
  'name': str,
  'job': [
      {
        'title': str,
        'location': str
      }
    ],
  'age': int
}
```

so that I can generate arbitrary data that follows whether it is a collection or a primitive, such that:

- if it is a collection, then keep all of the keys the same (or the size of the list the same)
- if it is a primitive, create fake data that matches the kind

This would, for instance, create a new dict for me that is something like:

```py
fake_dict = {
  'name': 'rsat98OULYR,
  'job': [
      {
        'title': 'qfwpRST(*&',
        'location': '.mk, rast0798'
      }
    ],
  'age': -46
}
```

So I don't need any *semantics* to be saved (eg, "name" doesn't carry any meaning other than being a string).  But I do need to keep all the data types.

Comment: Faker? Great Expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip install faker

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

name = fake.name()
city = fake.city()
country = fake.country()

print(f"Hello, World! My name is {name} and I'm from {city}, {country}.")
```

will output

```
Hello, World! My name is Michelle Gonzales and I'm from Brownstad, Saint Barthelemy.
```

https://pypi.org/project/Faker/

Comment: Thanks, excellent!  Not sure how I didn't know about this package, but it is excellent and does far more than I'd initially even hoped for!

Comment: It's incredibly useful for this exact kind of use case!